# Wpf MVVM Binding ListView to data other than DataContext

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am trying to create a usercontrol that shows a MainList and an OtherList that shows read only data from a different model.

I have already set my Datacontext like this:

```
xmlns:viewModel="clr-namespace:MyAssembly.ViewModel"

<UserControl.DataContext>
    <viewModel:MainListViewModel/>
</UserControl.DataContext>
```

And fill my mainList like this:

```
  <Grid>
      <ListView Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding MainList}">
          <ListView.View>
              <GridView>
                  <GridViewColumn Header="Col1" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col1}" />
                  <GridViewColumn Header="Col2" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col2}" />
                  <GridViewColumn Header="Col3" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Col3}" />
              </GridView>
          </ListView.View>
      </ListView>
  </Grid>

  <ListView Margin="10" ItemsSource="{Binding OtherList}">
      <ListView.View>
          <GridView>
              <GridViewColumn Header="OtherCol1" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding OtherCol1}" />
              <GridViewColumn Header="OtherCol2" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding OtherCol2}" />
              <GridViewColumn Header="OtherCol3" Width="Auto" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding OtherCol3}" />
          </GridView>
      </ListView.View>
  </ListView>
```

MainListViewModel.cs Looks like this and implements **INotifyPropertyChanged**:

```
private Datalayer=_datalayer;
public MainListViewModel()
{
    _datalayer= new Datalayer("connection");
    MainList = new ObservableCollection<MainListModel>(_dataLayer.GetMainList().Select(x => new MainlistModel(x)));
    OtherList = new ObservableCollection<OtherListModel>(_dataLayer.GetOtherList().Select(x => new OtherlistModel(x)));
}

    private ObservableCollection<MainListModel> _mainList;

    public ObservableCollection<MainListModel> MainList
    {
        get => _mainList;
        set
        {
            if (_mainList == value)
                return;
            _mainList = value;
            //below is inherited from the class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    private ObservableCollection<OtherListModel> _otherList;

    public ObservableCollection<OtherListModel> OtherList
    {
        get => _otherList;
        set
        {
            if (_otherList == value)
                return;
            _otherList = value;
            //below is inherited from the class that implements the INotifyPropertyChanged
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
```

Now, the above code works as intended for my MainList and i get the proper data to fill my OtherList with, but i cannot find a way to bind each field from the OtherListModel.

Also when i load this UserControl i get this exception:

InvalidOperationException: Operation is not valid while ItemsSource is in use. Access and modify elements with ItemsControl.ItemsSource instead.

This happens when the debugger reaches this point:

```
public ObservableCollection<OtherListModel> OtherList
{
    get => _otherList;
```

Comment: First of all, a UserControl should never explicitly set its own DataContext. Doing so breaks the way you would usually bind its properties, i.e. by Bindings that use the current, inherited DataContext as their source.

Comment: Why though? Is there any way to achieve what i am trying to do? I've been searching and i cannot find something.

Comment: Because the UserControl would operate on a DataContext that is not connected to the view model structure of the rest of the application. The Bindings in the control's XAML would work well against the object in an inherited DataContext, e.g the one provided by a container element with a DataTemplate that instantiates your control.

Comment: Ok. I kinda got it. I am fairly new to wpf/mvvm and it shows.
Either way because i am curious. Could this be done in some other concept?
Like, i want to have a list that when i select one of the rows the other list is filtered.
Keep in mind that the OtherList exists so i can only show information to the user. Not in any way interact with it